# TortoiseSVN Access to trunk forbidden when trying to create branch

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am trying to create a branch off of trunk in my project and Tortoise tells me that "access to '/svn/el_dev/!svn/bc/4656/trunk' forbidden". Does anyone have a clue about what this means and what I am doing wrong? I have verified that none of my colleagues are comitting and I have tried to create the branch at a number of different occasions with the same result.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had exactly the same kind of error today (that is why I found this question on StackOverflow). It turned out that I did not have **read** access to one of the subdirectories I wanted to branch, after an accidental change to authz.

So probably you do not have read access to one of the trunk directories.

Comment: Yes, that appears to be the problem.
Thanks!
(Sorry for the tardy response)